# When exactly should an avel (mourner) not be davening before the amud?

Tags: calendar, mourning-aveilus, chazzan-prayer-leader

An avel (mourner) if possible should also daven before the amud (be the chazan) on weekdays. But certain times of the year especially when tachanun is not said (but not every time) he should not be the chazan.

I find that the poskim are not very clear about this. When exactly should an avel (mourner) not be davening before the amud?

Answer (score 7):

[Nitei Gavriel Aveilus 56-58](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46540&st=&pgnum=412) discusses the different Minhagim. This is my understanding of what he says.

An Aveil should not Daven for the Amud on Shabbos, Yom Tov, and the high holy days. Exceptions are as follows. If there is no one who can Daven as good as the Aveil the Aveil may Daven during these days. In addition if the Aveil is the regular Chazan on the high holy days he may continue to Daven for the Amud on the high holy days. If he always Davened on Shabbos and Yom Tov for the Amud he may also continue to Daven for Shabbos and Yom Tov for the Amud. [56:6](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46540&st=&pgnum=415).

Erev Shabbos and Erev Yom Tov for Mincha, most Chasidim have the Minhag that an Aveil does not Daven for the Amud. The Minhag of the Ashkenazim is that the Aveil does Daven for the Amud. [56:10](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46540&st=&pgnum=416).

Regarding Selichos prior to Rosh HaShana and during the Aseres Yemai Teshuva there are different Minhagim. Some say an Aveil can say the Selichos even on Erev Rosh HaShana and some say an Aveil should not say the Selichos and should only Daven Shacharis from Ashrei / U'vo L'Tziyon. [56:15&16](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46540&st=&pgnum=419).

Rosh Chodesh there are differing Minhagim. Some say an Aveil can Daven everything besides Hallel and Musaf. Others say an Aveil should not Daven for the Amud on Rosh Chodesh at all, not even for Maariv. Then there are those that say an Aveil should Daven Mincha and Maariv for the Amud, however not Shacharis, Hallel and Musaf. [57:1](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46540&st=&pgnum=427).

Chol HaMoed an Aveil should not Daven for the Amud. [57:4](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46540&st=&pgnum=429).

Chanuka an Aveil Davens all Tefilos besides Hallel for the Amud. However there are those that have a Minhag not to Daven at all for the Amud on Chanuka. Then there are thise that Daven Mincha and Maariv for the Amud, however they do not Daven Shacharis for the Amud. [58:1](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46540&st=&pgnum=430).

Purim most people do not Daven at all for the Amud. Then there those that Daven from Ashrei / U'vo L'Tziyon. [59:1](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46540&st=&pgnum=435).

Shushan Purim some Daven all the Tefilos and some do not. [59:3](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46540&st=&pgnum=437).

Purim Katan, some say that the Aveil does not Daven at all for the Amud, however most have the Minhag that the Aveil does Daven for the Amud. [59:4](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46540&st=&pgnum=438).

**The Shaalos U'Teshuvos Megidos 83 (Pri Megadim) and Biur Halacha 132 say that any day we do not say Lamnatzaiach by Shacharis the Aveil does not Daven for the Amud.**

Some say an Aveil should not Daven for the Amud the entire Tishrei and entire Nisan unless the Aveil has Yarzheit on that day. [60](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46540&st=&pgnum=438).

Pesach Sheni, Lag B'omer, Chamisha Asar B'Av, Chamish Asar B'Shevat, from Rosh Chodesh Sivan until Isru Chag, Tisha B'Av - all have different Minhagim where some do all, some do none, and some do some. [60](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46540&st=&pgnum=440).

Comment: A very detailed answer except you missed today erev yom kippur when one does not say lamnatseach and the ovel does daven. The exception to the rule. That is why I asked it.

Comment: If your question was specific to one day then you should say so in your question. Your question was when one does not Daven, which I have given you much details. On Erev Yom Kippur, you are correct an Aveil does Daven however you were asking when not. http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46540&st=&pgnum=426

Comment: Your detailed answer also contained when they can daven even though as you rightly say the question did not ask it. So why leave out erev yom kippur.

Comment: Since it is agreed by all that an Avei Davens then.

Comment: Yes. But if you mention a rule you also have to state the exceptions. Otherwise one would think the rule applies there and one doesnt daven on erev yom kippur.

Comment: "from the amud" not "for the amud". The amud doesn't need our prayers.

Comment: @Gershon Gold - Do all of these exceptions apply to someone with yahrtzeit as well or does this only apply to someone who is in the year?

Comment: @Draizy-Levi Pine one who had Yahrzheit Davens on the day of the Yahrzheit even it is one of the listed days.

Comment: @GershonGold these practices seem to relate to a sad person leading the congregation at a time of joy ( http://havolim.blogspot.com/2019/03/vayikra-fiscal-probity-prerequisite.html ) but would this also apply to blowing shofar (assuming that there are others who could do it)?

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a debate whether one who is aveilus for one parent, can daven for the amud on the yahrzeit of the other parent

Comment: Thanks for this additional answer, and welcome to Mi Yodeya! Since most of us don't know you (to take your word on it), [edit]ing in sources for what you say is important.

Answer (score -1):

My rav specifically tells those in aveilus not to daven for the amud for mincha on erev Pesach.

You also left out that a aveil does not daven on Yom Ha'atzmaut and Yom Yerushalyim.

Comment: the great debater, this answer would be more helpful if you could include information on who your _rav_ is and your source for your second paragraph.